# Haskell building a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am trying to build a list of tuples. Input is a list of tuples `[([char], int1, int2), ...]` and the output is the list of tuples such that `[([char], int1, int2, (int1/int2)), ...]`. I know that this code below is wrong because I think it is building a list of lists of tuples `[[(),(),(),()], [(),(),(),()]]`.

Code:

```
{- take a list of labels, values, and weights and return list of labels and fractions -}
fraclist [] = []
fraclist x = [ (y,r,q,z) : y <- first (head x) | r <- scnd (head x) | q <- last (head x) | z <- r/q ] : fraclist tail x

{- helper func to get values from tuples -}
frst (a,b,c) = a
scnd (a,b,c) = b
last (a,b,c) = c
```

How might I get the proper output form as described? Also, how might I output the list of tuples ordered such that the z's are in descending order?

Comment: What errors are you getting?  What happens if you add type declarations to the function with the type you intend?

Comment: Well first I am getting this error... "parse error on input `<-'" which is making me mad because I can't really get it to compile even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code doesn't compile (syntax errors), but after fixing that (I'd recommend reading up on the [syntax of list comprehensions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension) (','s vs. '|'s)) and making some other changes:

- used a list comprehension, which takes care of the base case and the mapping over the list -- so I was able to eliminate `fraclist [] = []` and the `head`/`tail`/`:` business
- used pattern matching to pull the values out of the input tuples -- this is often much easier to read than using functions to take apart values
- added an explicit type signature for documentation purposes

here's what I think you meant:

```
fraclist :: (Integral t1) => [(t, t1, t1)] -> [(t, t1, t1, t1)]
fraclist xs = [(x, y, z, div y z) | (x, y, z) <- xs]
```

I'll leave the sorting to you.

Comment: Ok, So I notice this leaves another issues. I would like the output fractions to be as fractions. Such that 1/2 = .5 and not 0. Do I need to change the Integral to something? Such as Num or Fractional, also/or do I need to change the use of div to another function that divides and returns fractional output?

Comment: @BumSkeeter yes, if you want that, you will have to replace `div` with an appropriate function (like `/`) and change the type signature correspondingly.  [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is an excellent resource for finding an appropriate function.

Comment: Ok this works nicely. So one question. Why does this go over all of the tuples in the list and not just the first? shouldn't recursion be happening somewhere? And what does "(x, y, z) <- xs" do?

Comment: @BumSkeeter please see **[the link](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension)** I gave in my post -- it does a far better job of explaining list comprehensions than I could.  But the short answer is that list comprehensions take care of processing the list so that you don't have to explicitly recur.

Comment: @BumSkeeter Amusingly, your last question is the answer to the first two. `(x, y, z) <- xs` does two things. First, it loops over each element in `xs`. Second, it pattern-matches each element in `xs` against the pattern `(x, y, z)`, binding the three names to each value in the tuple.

Comment: So in this comprehension, we go over each tuple in the list mapping the values in the tuples to x,y,z and building the list of tuples such that the tuples conform to the stuff in-front of the pipe "(x, y, z, div y z)"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want just

```
fraclist xs = [(y,r,q, r `quot` q) | (y,r,q) <- xs]
```

(Note: I used `quot` instead of `(/)` since you named the components `int1`, `int2`.)

A variant not using list comprehensions is

```
fraclist = map (\(y,r,q) -> (y,r,q, r `quot` q))
```

Your code doesn't compile, in such cases it is better to post the error message so people can see at one glance what the probable cause is.

You get a parse erro on the first `<-` in

```
fraclist x = [ (y,r,q,z) : y <- first (head x) | r <- scnd (head x) | q <- last (head x) | z <- r/q ] : fraclist tail x
```

because the expression `(y,r,q,z) : y <- first (head x)` before the first `|` separating the generated expressions from the generator expressions isn't well-formed. I think it's just a typo and you meant to use `|` instead of `(:)` there too.

Then you have several `|` separators in your list comprehension, which is not valid without the `ParallelListComp` extension. However, the code doesn't look like a parallel list comprehension is really what you attempt here, since all three values are drawn from the same list. Finally, the last part `| z <- r/q` is again not well-formed, since `r/q` is not a list from which elements can be drawn in a list comprehension. You probably intended `let z = r/q` there.

Comment: No need to be sorry. We're all new to something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution without list comprehension:

```
import Data.List

-- (string, int1, int2) -> (string int1, int2, (int1/int2))
fraclist list = map generateTuple list
    where generateTuple (label, value, weight) = (label, value, weight, (value)/(weight)) 

sortFracListByValueWeightRatio list = sortBy sorter list
    where sorter (_,_,_,d) (_,_,_,h) = if d > h then GT else LT

testList = [("first",3.0,4.0), ("second",4.0,7.0)]
```

Nothing fancy (I've only used haskell a week).

**fraclist** works by mapping the generateTuple function to the list. The **generateTuple** function simply returns a tuple of form (title, value, weight, value/weight). **Map** is a built in function which simply applies a given function to each element of the list.

The **sortFracListByValueWeightRatio** (sorry for the long name) uses the built in **sortBy** function (comes from Data.List), which sorts a given list using a custom function for comparing items. **Sorter** is my item comparer, and it simply compares the value/weight ratios and returns either GT or LT (Greater Than / Lower Than). Hence, the list items are compared using the custom comparer, and sorted based on its answer.

A significant improvement of readability would probably be to use types to describe the values instead of just tuples. Also I'm using doubles in the test list, but that is easy to change.

Comment: I feel like this is too much of a "gimme teh codez" answer that doesn't give enough explanation.  Also, I think this is significantly *less* readable, and more complicated, than a list comprehension.

Comment: I just noticed your list comprehension answer now and I agree, it is more elegant (I haven't gotten to list comprehensions yet in Real World Haskell). At least I hope I contributed with a sensible way of sorting the list.

Comment: I only mentioned it to try and encourage you to explain your answer more -- an answer with a detailed, thoughtful explanation is worth **much** more than an answer that only has some code.

Comment: @MattFenwick I just updated my post. Thanks for the comment, this is my second ever answer on Stack Overflow (I'm a lurker) but I think its better now :)